# Black Lion: upcoming sales and 40% off key bundles?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Is there a way to know if a sale will be coming to an item soon? Essentially just marking an item into a "wishlist" of sorts and being notified when it's on sale.

And -- excuse the closely-related double-question -- has anyone purchased a key bundle for a friend and seen a reduction of 40% for themselves, due to this month's gift special?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to create a wishlist to monitor item prices for guild wars 2

Comment: What do you mean by key bundle? Because I have both bought and received gifts this month involving the discounts

Comment: Meaning I purchase 25 black lion keys for someone, as a whole, and then get 40% off on the same 25-key bundle.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the only way of knowing about such trends is by staying tuned to their official channels https://www.guildwars2.com/en/news/
I have not heard of discounts like the key bundle that you mention but I wouldn't be surprised if they do occur, just a matter of checking regularly I'd say